# How to reassign an approval request in apex

Tags: apex, approval-process, approval-step

I want to reassign a queue assigned to an approval request using apex. How can i achieve this,

I have tried updating processInstanceWorkItem object but it was throwing insufficient access error

Answer (score 3):

To change the responsible for an approval request you have to update the `ActorId` field on the `ProcessInstanceWorkItem` object with the Id of the user you want to be the actual approver.

I just did this myself in a test org:

```
ProcessInstanceWorkItem pi = [SELECT Id, ActorId FROM ProcessInstanceWorkItem LIMIT 1];
pi.ActorId = '0051I0000027LCVQA2';
update pi;
```

And it worked just fine. I even got a message stating that the request was reassigned:

[image: reassignment]

Of course, I executed that snippet with an administrator user, so if you are trying to do this in, say, a trigger called by a non-admin user, you might want to take a look in the [**sharing keyword**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm). What you got might be an error due to the privileges for that non-admin user.

Comment: This approach works as a system admin or an approver for that particular record but not as anyone

Comment: Exactly. You won't be able to modify this record unless you have the permission to do so. Hence why I mentioned that you might want to run this update in System Mode instead (ignoring user permissions).